# Running a shell command on EC2 using boto?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python

I am trying to find a way to pass a shell command to a Linux EC2 instance.

Basically I have a script which creates an EBS Volume, brings up a CloudFormation stack, and then attaches the new volume to an EC2 instance within the stack.

What I want to do, is to format and mount that volume as part of this script, but I seem to have hit a road block at that point.

My python is not awesome, but I have managed to get through most of this, while learning a bunch at the same time.  I considered using Paramiko, however I need to tunnel through a couple of servers to get to the subnet of the instances.

```
# Attach an EBS volume to the EC2 Server instance
def attach_ebs(stack_id, results_volume):
    resources = cfn.list_stack_resources(stack_id)
    for r in resources:
        if r.resource_type == "AWS::EC2::Instance" and "Server" in r.logical_resource_id:
            ec2.attach_volume(results_volume, r.physical_resource_id, "/dev/sdh")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module to execute a command through ssh in the target instance.

To avoid the jumphost mess consider executing your python script from a EC2 instance with the right IAM role. Or use [ssh-chain](https://github.com/ryancdotorg/ssh-chain).